# Math captcha session value not passing

Tags: php, javascript, validation, session, captcha

I am working with a contact form. My problem is I am not able to validate captcha. `isset($_session[''])` does not work.

My code:

contact.php

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['num1']) && !isset($_SESSION['num2'])) {
    $_SESSION['num1'] = rand(1,5);
    $_SESSION['num2'] = rand(1,5);
  }
?>
```

Showing Captcha field:

```php
<label for="captcha">
  <?php echo $_SESSION['num1']; ?>+ <?php echo $_SESSION['num2']; ?>?
</label>
<input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha">
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("nourl", function(value, element) {
    return !/http\:\/\/|www\.|link\=|url\=/.test(value);
  }, "No URL's");

  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      comments: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        nourl: true
      },
      captcha: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
          url: "validation.php",
          type: "post"
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      comments: "",
      captcha: ""
    }
  });
});
```

validation.php:

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['num1']) || !isset($_SESSION['num2'])) {
    exit('"Unknown session"');
  }
  $sum = (int)$_SESSION['num1'] + (int)$_SESSION['num2'];
  if (isset($_POST['captcha']) && (int)$_POST['captcha'] === $sum) {
    exit('true');
  }
  exit('false');
?>
```

Result I am getting: "Unknown session"

Every time getting this line return.

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['num1']) || !isset($_SESSION['num2'])) {
  exit('"Unknown session"');
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you written `session_start()` in the file that shows the captcha field? Also I'd recommend using an interval larger than 1-5 as it doesn't provide that many different equations.

Comment: You are asking about validation.php
i added session_start() at both page

Comment: ur not sending the data in jquery...